# Float element right, but make it appear after in the HTML

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following markup:

```
<style>
  button {
    float: right;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    button {
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
    }
  }
</style>

<div>
  <button>Book now</button>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

What I want is:

1. to have the text wrap the button on medium & large devices:
   [image: text wrapping around button]
2. to have a full-width button **after** the text on mobile devices:
   [image: button full width after the text]

**However, I can't manage to get both.**

---

If I put the button before the text in the HTML, I get the text wrapping all right, but the button appears *before* the text on mobile:

[image: button appears before text]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nswptc3s/1/

---

And if I put the button after the text in the HTML, the button appears after the text on mobile all right, but the text does not wrap the button on larger devices:

[image: text does not wrap button]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nswptc3s/2/

---

**How can I get both?** Note that I don't want to give a fixed width to the button or the paragraph (so I can't just float the `<p>` as well).

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: I'm using Foundation, but I can't use the grid for this one, as I don't want *fixed widths*.

Comment: This is a beginning. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nswptc3s/5/)

Comment: Not sure you understood what I said twice: I don't want fixed widths!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed by fixed you meant hardcoded in pixels, and not percentages.

Comment: No worries, I want the entire thing to be flexible, and adapt to the button size!

Comment: Also, if you're using Foundationas a front end framework, you might want to add that as a tag.

Comment: @SatejS Nope, it's not foundation-related: the question is the same whether I'm using Foundation, Bootstrap, or no CSS framework. I wouldn't tag my database just because I'm using it on the same project :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floats are not supposed to be used for layout. Better use flexbox.

```css
div {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins */
  align-items: center; /* Center button vertically */
}
p {
  flex: 1; /* Occupy the remaining space left by the button */
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  div {
    flex-direction: column; /* Switch to column layout */
    align-items: stretch; /* Stretch the button horizontally */
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
p {
  flex: 1;
}
button {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: transparent;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  div {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id eleifend velit. Maecenas feugiat consequat finibus. Aenean enim quam, tincidunt nec laoreet a, scelerisque et dolor.
  </p>
  <button>
    Book now
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is great, and your example works as expected, thanks. I'm just concerned by the fact that it doesn't work on IE9, which still has a few % market share at the moment.